# Java generics in pipeline architecture

Tags: java, generics, interface, architecture

I have a base abstract class `PipelineStage` which has the following definition:

```
public abstract class PipelineStage<I, O> implements Runnable {

    ...

    public abstract O step(I input);

    ...

}
```

I then have numerous concrete pipeline stages with definitions such as:

```
public class ConcreteStage extends PipelineStage<InputContextClass, OutputContextClass> {

    ...

    @Override
    public OutputContextClass step(InputContextClass input) {
        input.someMethod();
        ...
        return new OutputContextClass();
    }

    ...

}
```

However, this has led to a rigid design in which either:

1. The context classes are very tightly coupled to which stages they are used in.
2. Every stage needs to have two full interfaces defined, defining all the properties of the input and output classes.

I wanted to improve this design by having generic interfaces that specify properties of the context classes, the ConcreteStage would then specify what interfaces it's input and output context classes must extend.

However, I can't figure out how to do this in a way the compiler likes.

For example:

```
public class ConcreteStage extends PipelineStage<I extends Interface1 & Interface2, 
    O extends Interface2 & Interface3> {

    ...

    @Override
    public O step(I input) {
        input.someMethodFromInterface1();
        input.someMethodFromInterface2();
        ...
        // OutputContextClass extends Interface2 & Interface3
        return new OutputContextClass();
    }

    ...

}
```

However, this doesn't compile, showing that class `I` needs to be imported.

A wildcard also doesn't work, saying `No wildcard expected`.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement this in a neat, flexible way? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a guess, shouldn't `I` and `O` now become generic parameters of `ConcreteStage`, like `ConcreteStage<I, O>`

Comment: @DanilGaponov Your idea is the same as Andy Turner's answer, I replied to his answer about why I don't think that's an entirely appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the type variable declarations on the class, not the superclass:

```
public static class ConcreteStage<
          I extends Interface1 & Interface2, O extends Interface2 & Interface3>
      extends PipelineStage<I, O> {
```

Comment: The issue with this is that the instantiation of ConcreteStage then requires those types specified, when really that's more of an implementation detail. The user of the class doesn't need to know what class it's using to communicate inside the pipeline.

Comment: I guess this comes from the fact that a user of the pipeline creates a `Pipeline` object, then creates multiple `PipelineStage` instances, then does `Pipeline.add(PipelineStage)`. If instead, the user didn't directly instantiate `PipelineStage` instances, but just indicated which ones they wanted to use (such as with an enum that maps to concrete classes) then the `Pipeline` class could do the instantiation and somewhat protect the implementation details.

Comment: You can't have it both ways: you can either be generic, and have the user specify the input and output types; or you can be specific by declaring the concrete types in the `extends PipelineStage<InputType, OutputType>`, and have the user not need to specify them, but unable to change them.

Comment: (Well, I suppose you can have it a third way, and use raw types. But that would be particularly ill-advised, since you lose type safety)

Comment: I think I want the package to be aware of the context types, but the external user of the pipeline to not be. Would you say that using an enum to specify which stages you want in the pipeline is a good idea?


Edit: Actually, making the user decide which classes are passed between stages might be a good way to ensure the user checks that two sequential stages have the same type between them. So maybe it isn't the best idea to hide it afterall?

Comment: @IsaacJordan you can only use an enum if all of the stages of the pipeline have the same input and output types: if you can configure stages to be on and off at runtime, both `I` and `O` have to be the same, so that any stage's output can be used as any other stage's input.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make an interface uniting input interfaces together `interface InputInterface12 extends InputInterface1, InputInterface2 {}` and then `class ConcreteStage extends PipelineStage<InputInterface12, OutputInterface12> {...}`.

Comment: I actually considered that, and it is a valid solution. The downside is that you'll have around 2 times as many context interfaces as pipeline stages (depending on much you can reuse), which isn't particularly handy as I have ~ 12 stages and growing.